# Unintentional Output Shape: Generative Adversarial Network

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

So im working on this project that generates images of fruits and so far i have most of the actual code written but I'm running into this very strange problem. i followed the https://towardsdatascience.com/gan-by-example-using-keras-on-tensorflow-backend-1a6d515a60d0 tutorial about hand written digits and though i could mess with it but my code is giving me the error that somehow the output shape (28, 28, 1) is still showing up in the generator model instead of my (100, 100, 3) could anyone explain this strange problem of mine?

here's my code:

```
import numpy as np;
import time;
#import training data

from keras.models import Sequential;
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Flatten, Reshape;
from keras.layers import Conv2D, Conv2DTranspose, UpSampling2D;
from keras.layers import LeakyReLU, Dropout;
from keras.layers import BatchNormalization;
from keras.optimizers import Adam, RMSprop;

class GAN(object):
    def __init__(self, img_rows, img_cols, channel):

        self.img_rows = img_rows;
        self.img_cols = img_cols;
        self.channel = channel;
        self.D = None;
        self.G = None;
        self.AM = None;
        self.DM = None;

    
    def discriminator(self):
        if self.D:
            return self.D;
        self.D = Sequential();
        depth = 64;
        dropout = 0.4;

        input_shape = (self.img_rows, self.img_cols, self.channel);
        self.D.add(Conv2D(depth*1, 5, strides=2, input_shape=input_shape, padding='same'));
        self.D.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2));
        self.D.add(Dropout(dropout));

        self.D.add(Conv2D(depth*2, 5, strides=2, padding='same'));
        self.D.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2));
        self.D.add(Dropout(dropout));

        self.D.add(Conv2D(depth*4, 5, strides=2, padding='same'));
        self.D.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2));
        self.D.add(Dropout(dropout));

        self.D.add(Conv2D(depth*8, 5, strides=1, padding='same'));
        self.D.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2));
        self.D.add(Dropout(dropout));

        self.D.add(Flatten());
        self.D.add(Dense(1));
        self.D.add(Activation('sigmoid'));
        self.D.summary();
        return self.D;

    def generator(self):
        if self.G:
            return self.G;
        self.G = Sequential();
        dropout = 0.4;
        depth = 64+64+64+64;
        dim = 7;
        
        self.G.add(Dense(dim*dim*depth, input_dim=100));
        self.G.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.9));
        self.G.add(Activation('relu'));
        self.G.add(Reshape((dim, dim, depth)));
        self.G.add(Dropout(dropout));

        self.G.add(UpSampling2D());
        self.G.add(Conv2DTranspose(int(depth/2), 5, padding='same'));
        self.G.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.9));
        self.G.add(Activation('relu'));


        self.G.add(UpSampling2D());
        self.G.add(Conv2DTranspose(int(depth/4), 5, padding='same'));
        self.G.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.9));
        self.G.add(Activation('relu'));

        self.G.add(Conv2DTranspose(int(depth/8), 5, padding='same'));
        self.G.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.9));
        self.G.add(Activation('relu'));

        self.G.add(Conv2DTranspose(1, 5, padding='same'));
        self.G.add(Activation('sigmoid'));
        self.G.summary();
        return self.G;

    def discriminator_model(self):
        if self.DM:
            return self.DM;
        optimizer = RMSprop(lr=0.0002, decay=6e-8);
        self.DM = Sequential();
        self.DM.add(self.discriminator());
        self.DM.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy']);
        return self.DM;

    def adversarial_model(self):
        if self.AM:
            return self.AM;
        optimizer = RMSprop(lr=0.0001, decay=3e-8);
        self.AM = Sequential();
        self.AM.add(self.generator());
        self.AM.add(self.discriminator());
        self.AM.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy']);
        return self.AM;

class Fruit_GAN:
    def __init__(self):
        self.img_rows = 28;
        self.img_cols = 28;
        self.channel = 1;
        print('\nstarting\n');
        self.GAN = GAN(self.img_rows, self.img_cols, self.channel);
        print('\nGAN setup succeded\n');
        self.discriminator = self.GAN.discriminator_model();
        print('\ndiscriminator setup succeded\n');
        self.adversarial = self.GAN.adversarial_model();
        print('\nadversarial setup succeded\n');
        self.generator = self.GAN.generator();
        print('\ngenerator setup succeded\n');
        
    def Train(self, train_steps=2000, batch_size=256, save_interval=0):
        noise_input = None;
        if save_interval>0:
            noise_input = np.random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0, size=[16, 100]);
        for i in range(train_steps):

            # training images:
            images_train = 0
            # random noise for generator:
            noise = np.random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0, size=[batch_size, 100]);
            # generator generated fake images:
            images_fake = self.generator.predict(noise);
            # train data formating for discriminator:
            x = np.concatenate((images_train, images_fake));
            y = np.ones([2*batch_size, 1]);
            y[batch_size:, :] = 0;
            # training_discriminator:
            d_loss = self.discriminator.train_on_batch(x, y);


            # train data reformatting for generator:
            y = np.ones([batch_size, 1]);
            noise = np.random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0, size=[batch_size, 100]);
            a_loss = self.adversarial.train_on_batch(noise, y);

            log_msg = "%d: [D loss: %f, acc: %f]" % (i, d_loss[0], d_loss[1]);
            log_msg = "%s: [A loss: %f, acc: %f]" % (log_mesg, a_loss[0], a_loss[1]);
            print(log_msg);

            if save_interval > 0:
                if (i+1) % save_interval == 0:
                    # save data
                    pass;

class ElapsedTimer(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.start_time = time.time()
    def elapsed(self,sec):
        if sec < 60:
            return str(sec) + " sec"
        elif sec < (60 * 60):
            return str(sec / 60) + " min"
        else:
            return str(sec / (60 * 60)) + " hr"
    def elapsed_time(self):
        print("Elapsed: %s " % self.elapsed(time.time() - self.start_time) );
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = Fruit_GAN();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well thats because you specified the shape of your generator as such, i took the liberty of changing the code to fix your output shape: (100, 100, 3)

```py
G = tf.keras.Sequential()
dropout = 0.4
depth = 64+64+64+64
# I've change this to 25 as its a multiple of 7 before (7 * 4 = 28)
# So to fix that i've changed it to 25 (25 * 4 = 100)
dim = 25 

# In: 100
# Out: dim x dim x depth
G.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(dim*dim*depth, input_dim=100))
G.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=0.9))
G.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu'))
G.add(tf.keras.layers.Reshape((dim, dim, depth)))
G.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(dropout))

# In: dim x dim x depth
# Out: 2*dim x 2*dim x depth/2
G.add(tf.keras.layers.UpSampling2D()) # Your upsampling layer is multiple of 2 
G.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(int(depth/2), 5, padding='same'))
G.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=0.9))
G.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu'))
G.add(tf.keras.layers.UpSampling2D())
G.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(int(depth/4), 5, padding='same'))
G.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=0.9))
G.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu'))
G.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(int(depth/8), 5, padding='same'))
G.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=0.9))
G.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu'))

# Out: 100 x 100 x 3 rgb image [0.0,1.0] per pix
G.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(3, 5, padding='same')) # Previously 1 representing 1 channel change to suit your rgb channel
G.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation('sigmoid'))
G.summary()

'''Final layer shape
activation_14 (Activation)   (None, 100, 100, 3)       0         
================================================================='''
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the generator part.

First put your eye on lines:

[image]

...and then put your finger to lines:

[image]

... and then begin to tune the dim of the generator (try different values for dim and check the output shape of the generator) and this way see the effect of the dim on the output of the generator. Adjust the other layers of the generator also if needed. This way you find the idea of need for adjustment of generator parameters when the size of image changes.

The debugged version of your code, producing now outputs of size (100,100,1) is:

```
import numpy as np;
import time;
#Those two imports were missing to reproduce and debug the problem...added...
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
#import training data

from keras.models import Sequential;
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Flatten, Reshape;
from keras.layers import Conv2D, Conv2DTranspose, UpSampling2D;
from keras.layers import LeakyReLU, Dropout;
from keras.layers import BatchNormalization;
from keras.optimizers import Adam, RMSprop;

class GAN(object):
    def __init__(self, img_rows, img_cols, channel):

        self.img_rows = img_rows;
        self.img_cols = img_cols;
        self.channel = channel;
        self.D = None;
        self.G = None;
        self.AM = None;
        self.DM = None;


    def discriminator(self):
        if self.D:
            return self.D;
        self.D = Sequential();
        depth = 64;
        dropout = 0.4;

        input_shape = (self.img_rows, self.img_cols, self.channel);
        print("Input shape nayttaa talta: ",input_shape)
        self.D.add(Conv2D(depth*1, 5, strides=2, input_shape=input_shape, padding='same'));
        self.D.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2));
        self.D.add(Dropout(dropout));

        self.D.add(Conv2D(depth*2, 5, strides=2, padding='same'));
        self.D.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2));
        self.D.add(Dropout(dropout));

        self.D.add(Conv2D(depth*4, 5, strides=2, padding='same'));
        self.D.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2));
        self.D.add(Dropout(dropout));

        self.D.add(Conv2D(depth*8, 5, strides=1, padding='same'));
        self.D.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2));
        self.D.add(Dropout(dropout));

        self.D.add(Flatten());
        self.D.add(Dense(1));
        self.D.add(Activation('sigmoid'));
        print("Diskriminaattori:")
        self.D.summary();
        print("Let's test it, note the shape of test input...")
        testitulos=self.D(tf.random.uniform((1,100,100,1)))
        print(testitulos)
        return self.D;

    def generator(self):
        if self.G:
            return self.G;
        self.G = Sequential();
        dropout = 0.4;
        depth = 64+64+64+64;
        #Let's modify the dim...
        dim = 25 #7;

        self.G.add(Dense(dim*dim*depth, input_dim=100));
        self.G.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.9));
        self.G.add(Activation('relu'));
        self.G.add(Reshape((dim, dim, depth)));
        self.G.add(Dropout(dropout));

        self.G.add(UpSampling2D());
        self.G.add(Conv2DTranspose(int(depth/2), 5, padding='same'));
        self.G.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.9));
        self.G.add(Activation('relu'));

        self.G.add(UpSampling2D());
        self.G.add(Conv2DTranspose(int(depth/4), 5, padding='same'));
        self.G.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.9));
        self.G.add(Activation('relu'));

        self.G.add(Conv2DTranspose(int(depth/8), 5, padding='same'));
        self.G.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.9));
        self.G.add(Activation('relu'));

        self.G.add(Conv2DTranspose(1, 5, padding='same'));
        self.G.add(Activation('sigmoid'));
        print("Generaattori:")
        self.G.summary();
        print("Let's test it, note the shape of the output of the generator...")
        testitulos=self.G(tf.random.uniform((1,100)))
        print(testitulos.shape)
        return self.G;

    def discriminator_model(self):
        if self.DM:
            return self.DM;
        optimizer = RMSprop(lr=0.0002, decay=6e-8);
        self.DM = Sequential();
        self.DM.add(self.discriminator());
        self.DM.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy']);
        return self.DM;

    def adversarial_model(self):
        if self.AM:
            return self.AM;
        optimizer = RMSprop(lr=0.0001, decay=3e-8);
        self.AM = Sequential();
        self.AM.add(self.generator());
        self.AM.add(self.discriminator());
        self.AM.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy']);
        return self.AM;

class Fruit_GAN:
    def __init__(self):
        self.img_rows = 100;
        self.img_cols = 100;
        self.channel = 1;
        print('\nstarting\n');
        self.GAN = GAN(self.img_rows, self.img_cols, self.channel);
        print('\nGAN setup succeded\n');
        self.discriminator = self.GAN.discriminator_model();
        print('\ndiscriminator setup succeded\n');
        self.adversarial = self.GAN.adversarial_model();
        print('\nadversarial setup succeded\n');
        self.generator = self.GAN.generator();
        print('\ngenerator setup succeded\n');

    def Train(self, train_steps=2000, batch_size=256, save_interval=0):
        noise_input = None;
        if save_interval>0:
            noise_input = np.random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0, size=[16, 100]);
        for i in range(train_steps):

            # training images:
            images_train = 0
            # random noise for generator:
            noise = np.random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0, size=[batch_size, 100]);
            # generator generated fake images:
            images_fake = self.generator.predict(noise);
            # train data formating for discriminator:
            x = np.concatenate((images_train, images_fake));
            y = np.ones([2*batch_size, 1]);
            y[batch_size:, :] = 0;
            # training_discriminator:
            d_loss = self.discriminator.train_on_batch(x, y);


            # train data reformatting for generator:
            y = np.ones([batch_size, 1]);
            noise = np.random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0, size=[batch_size, 100]);
            a_loss = self.adversarial.train_on_batch(noise, y);

            log_msg = "%d: [D loss: %f, acc: %f]" % (i, d_loss[0], d_loss[1]);
            log_msg = "%s: [A loss: %f, acc: %f]" % (log_mesg, a_loss[0], a_loss[1]);
            print(log_msg);

            if save_interval > 0:
                if (i+1) % save_interval == 0:
                    # save data
                    pass;

class ElapsedTimer(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.start_time = time.time()
    def elapsed(self,sec):
        if sec < 60:
            return str(sec) + " sec"
        elif sec < (60 * 60):
            return str(sec / 60) + " min"
        else:
            return str(sec / (60 * 60)) + " hr"
    def elapsed_time(self):
        print("Elapsed: %s " % self.elapsed(time.time() - self.start_time) );


if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = Fruit_GAN();
```

Comment: If you don't mind me commenting, doesn't the question require a 3 channel image?